# complex fourier series problem Cn term

Tags: education

can anyone help with this complex fourier series problem (in details please specially the Cn term) (as in the attached picture)[here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cNNM.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer of you show us that you made some effort. Besides, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), please.

Comment: I don't get your problem and where you stuck. It the integration the problem? There you already have $\cos(t/2)=\frac12(e^{(t/2)j}+e^{-(t/2)j})$ and therefore $\int \cos(t/2)e^{-jnt}~dt=\frac12\left(\int e^{((1/2)-n)tj}~dt+\int e^{-((1/2)+n)tj}~dt\right)=\frac12\left(\frac{-j}{(1/2)-n}e^{((1/2)-n)tj}+\frac{j}{(1/2)+n}e^{-((1/2)-n)tj}\right)$

Comment: @Mundron Schmidt Actually, he had $\cos\frac{t}2=\frac{e^{jt/2}-e^{−jt/2}}2,$ and that may have been the problem.

Comment: yes, exactly the cos(t/2) making some problem to me, can you help with that ?

Comment: here is my attempt (i hope it is clear):
part 1>> https://i.imgur.com/KPqQ62W.png   
part 2>> https://i.imgur.com/gwxsMU1.jpg
part 3>> https://i.imgur.com/99mNVn1.jpg
part 4>> https://i.imgur.com/AHAWtKr.jpg

and here is the original solution:
https://i.imgur.com/vNPcBdw.jpg


 (how did he came with this results of Cn) where is my mistake?

Comment: @ProfessorVector kindly check my above comment

Comment: @MundronSchmidt kindly check my above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I see your problem. There are three mistakes in your computation.

1.

Like ProfessorVector mentioned: You have a sign mistake in your cosine identity. It is $\cos(x)=\frac12(e^{xi}+e^{-xi})$.

2.

On sheet 2 you change $\frac{2(j+2jn)}{-(1-4n^2)}$ to $\frac{2(j+2n\pi)}{-(1-4n^2)}$. How did $j$ become $\pi$? That's wrong. Further, you are not consequent in your computation. So started with $\int\ldots$ and in the middle part, you included the factor $\frac1{4\pi}$ out of the blue. The right solution of your sheet $2$ should be
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{(1/2-n)tj}~dt=\frac{2(1+2n)j}{-(1-4n^2)}(-1)^n\left(e^{\frac{\pi}2j}-e^{-\frac{\pi}2j}\right).
$$
If you use the identities $e^{\frac{\pi}2j}=j$ and $e^{-\frac{\pi}2j}=-j$ you get
$$
\frac{2(1+2n)j}{-(1-4n^2)}(-1)^n\left(e^{\frac{\pi}2j}-e^{-\frac{\pi}2j}\right)=\frac{2(1+2n)j}{-(1-4n^2)}(-1)^n2j=(-1)^n\frac{4(1+2n)}{1-4n^2}.
$$
It is more useful to get $e^{\frac{\pi}2j}-e^{-\frac{\pi}2j}=2j$ insteat of $2\sinh\left(\frac{\pi}2j\right)$.

3.

On sheet 3, your computation seems right, but when you included the result on sheet 4, you changed again $j$ to $\pi$. And using the identities as above you should get
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-(1/2+n)tj}~dt=(-1)^n\frac{4(1-2n)}{1-4n^2}.
$$
Finally you can combine the results and you get
\begin{align}
C_n&=\frac1{4\pi}\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{(1/2-n)tj}+\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-(1/2+n)tj}\right)\\
&=\frac1{4\pi}\left((-1)^n\frac{4(1+2n)}{1-4n^2}+(-1)^n\frac{4(1-2n)}{1-4n^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\pi}\left(\frac{1+2n}{1-4n^2}+\frac{1-2n}{1-4n^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n\cdot 2}{\pi(1-4n^2)}
\end{align}

Comment: can't thank you enough for you time Mr. @Mundron Schmidt mission accomplished.


I have a question: can we get the same results if we use the sinh identity instead of the (j) and (-j) that you mentioned above ??

Comment: and thanks indeed for your notice Mr. @ProfessorVector

Comment: kindly can you check the previous comment

Comment: is it possible to get the same solution using the (Sinh) identity instead of the (j) identity that you mentioned before ?

Comment: Hello Dear Mr. @Mundron Schmidt
i didn't find the (j) identity that you mentioned before anywhere, can you may be give more details about it ?

Comment: You might know the Euler identity $e^{tj}=\cos(t)+\sin(t)j$. Include $t=\pm\frac{\pi}2$ and compute $\cos\left(\pm\frac{\pi}2\right)=0$ while $\sin\left(\pm\frac{\pi}2\right)=\pm1$.

Comment: very helpful, thanks indeed for your time. @Mundron Schmidt

is it possible to get the same results if we use the (Sinh) identity ?

Comment: I think you can check yourself what will happen. Hint: Where was it useful to have $j$ instead of $\sinh$?

Comment: I will check, thanks indeed @MundronSchmidt

Comment: Hello dear Mr. @Mundron Schmidt
am trying to solve this Fourier Trans. problem,
here is my attempt, 
part 1>> https://i.imgur.com/DT2tJ0y.jpg
part 2>> https://i.imgur.com/jopEoQd.jpg
part 3>> https://i.imgur.com/cKXoekT.jpg

and here is the original solution >> https://i.imgur.com/eJJ5FLF.png

How did he come up with this result and where is my mistake?

Comment: Hello dear mr. @MundronSchmidt , can you help me with my last comment...

Comment: Hello dear Mr. @Mundron Schmidt am trying to solve this Fourier Trans. problem, here is my attempt, 
part 1>> i.imgur.com/DT2tJ0y.jpg 
part 2>> i.imgur.com/jopEoQd.jpg 
part 3>> i.imgur.com/cKXoekT.jpg 
and here is the original solution >> i.imgur.com/eJJ5FLF.png 
How did he come up with this result and where is my mistake? can you spot the mistakes ?

Comment: hello mr can you spot my mistake on the last comment??

Comment: Please make a new question for a new problem.

Comment: Ok, Mr. @Mundron Schmidt , i actually made the new question in a comment because the website didn't let me post a new one which i needed urgently, that's why i made it in a comment.